# Probability intersection of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let the sample space be S = 1,2,3,4,5,6 with probability function p.

and $p(1)=p(2)=p(3)=p(5) = \frac{1}{8}$ and $p(4)=p(6) = \frac{1}{4}$

Define the events $E = 2,4,6$ and $F = 2,3,5$ Give the calcutlation that gives $P(E \mid F) = \frac{1}{2}$. Are $E,F$ independent?

My book is not clear at all, it gives $P(E\mid F) = \frac{P(E \cap F)}{P(F)} $

$P(E \cap F) = 1/8$ and $P(F) = 3/8$

that doesn't give $\frac{1}{2}$ it gives $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Strange that $P(E\ |\ F)=\frac{1}{2}$ has to be shown whereas $P(E\ |\ F=\frac{1}{3})$ is obviously correct.

Comment: To decide whether $E$ and $F$ are independent, compare $P(E\cap F)$ with $P(E)P(F)$.

Comment: not independent since $\frac{1}{3} \neq \frac{15}{64}$

Comment: The correct reason is $\frac{1}{8}\neq \frac{15}{64}$. Do not mix $P(E\ | F)$ with $P(E\cap F)$!

Comment: @Peter oh yes, thank you!

Comment: What is the book?